# Save and fetch from TextField in CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data, save, fetch

I want to save and fetch Data from a TextField. My Code looks like:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
private var currentTextField: UITextField?

var Detail: [NSManagedObject] = [ ]

@IBOutlet weak var TableViewDetail: UITextView!   
@IBOutlet weak var LabelDetail: UILabel!  
@IBOutlet weak var TextField: UITextField!
```

Save button:

```
@IBAction func SaveButton(_ sender: Any) {    
    if (TextField.text ==  "") {
        self.save2(TextField.text!)
    }

    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {return}
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    do {

        try managedContext.save()

    } catch let err as NSError {
        print("Cant save arrangement", err)
    }

    print("TextFieldEditingEnd2")
}
```

Is this necessary?

```
@IBAction func Submit(sender: UIButton) {
    if let currentTextField = currentTextField {
        currentTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

I think here is the error generated:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if (TextField.text !=  "")
    {
        currentTextField = textField
        print("TextFieldEditingEnd2")
        if  CoreDataHandler.saveDetail(itemDetail: (currentTextField?.text!)!) {
        for item in CoreDataHandler.fetchDetail()!  {
            print("\(String(describing: item.itemDetail))")
            }}
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    TextField.delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // func viewDidload(_ animated: Bool) {    
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // User finished typing (hit return): hide the keyboard.
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

The save function

```
func save2(_ itemName: String){

    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "ItemDetail", in: managedContext)!
    let showItemDetail = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)

    showItemDetail.setValue(itemName, forKey: "itemDetail")

    do {
        try managedContext.save()
    } catch let err as NSError {
        print("Failed to save item",err) 
    }

}
```

There is an Error

> [SmallApps.DetailViewController TextFieldIO:]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0x7fad6de3dc10'

*** First throw call stack:"

Has somebody an advise?

**EDIT:**
The save and fetch fuctions:

**Save:**

```
class func saveDetail(itemDetail: String) -> Bool {
    let context = getContext()
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "ItemDetail", in: context)
    let manageObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
    manageObject.setValue(UITextField.self, forKey: "itemDetail")
    do {
        try context.save()
        return true
    }catch {
        return false
    }
}
```

**fetch:**

```
class func fetchDetail() -> [ItemDetail]? {
    let context = getContext()
    var showItemDetail:[ItemDetail]? = nil
    do {
        showItemDetail = try context.fetch(ItemDetail.fetchRequest())
        return showItemDetail
    }catch {
        return showItemDetail
    }
}
```

Comment: `currentTextField = textField` why this? Since you have `TextField`.

Comment: func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) did not work. Referring to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322944/uitextfield-doesnt-end-editing-when-button-clicked-delegate-textfielddidendedi

Comment: When do you get this error? After clicking submit button?

Comment: And try replacing `(TextField.text !=  "")` with `textField.text != ""`. and if the error still persists, `textFieldDidEndEditing` is not causing the error.

Comment: When editing is ending but not when i click the "save" button

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: Added the save and fetch functions above

Comment: `manageObject.setValue(UITextField.self, forKey: "itemDetail")`. Shouldn't you be saving the text instead of `UITextField` itself?

Answer (score 0):

Save the **itemDetail** not **UITextField** itself.

For: `textFieldDidEndEditing` that calls `CoreHandler.saveDetail`

**Use one save function**:

```
 func saveDetail(itemDetail: String) {
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return false }
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "ItemDetail", in: context)
    let manageObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
    manageObject.setValue(itemDetail, forKey: "itemDetail")
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        .. handle catch
    }
}
```

For `SaveButton` that is calling `save2()` function.
You are not saving anything inside **SaveButton**

```
@IBAction func SaveButton(_ sender: Any) { 
    // You are comparing TextField.text == "" and saving? If text is not empty you are trying to save. So use != 
    if let text = TextField.text, text != "" { 
        saveDetail(itemDetail: text)
    }  
}
```

Some advices:

1. Your **variable names** are against **Swift** guidelines. Please use
   **camelCase**.
2. Do not use **!(force cast)** on variables instead use optional chaining through **if** or **guard** statements.
3. You are saving from lot of places. Follow **DRY** principle. Have one API to save to CoreData.
4. **saveDetail** should not be returning bool. Violates **Command-Query** separation.

Comment: I think the error was generated because of an unused "TextViewIO". But saving does not work yet. Another tip?

Comment: TextViewIO is unrelated. Anyways the error is solved? Did you try the above solution?  I think you need to update your question if you have a different problem.

Comment: Well, not solved, i still cannot save the data from/into the TextField, but the error is gone. Thank you for your help and the advices. Very apprecciated. Thanks!

Comment: @Winz You are using TextField.text == "" and saving it? I think there is a logical error.

Comment: Should not that be done by `func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)` ?

Comment: Question 1: Are you able to save when pressing SaveButton? If no then your TextField.text == "" is causing a logical error. See Answer Update 2.

Comment: Oh yes "TextField.text == "" and saving it", that is wrong, but still does not work without the if query.

Comment: Use `if` but correct the logical error and remove duplicate and unnecessary codes below it. Check my answer.

Comment: Save button does not work. Func `textFieldDidEndEditing` is not reachable anymore

Comment: @Winz I have updated my answer with one `saveDetail` function. Use it anywhere you are trying to save itemDetail. I have tested it and it works.

Comment: Alright, i had time to test and something is saved now. But the TextField only shows [<ItemDetail: 0x6040002890b0> (entity: ItemDetail; id: 0xd000000000040002 <x-coredata://4A34A20C-5A8B-41DC-7D49-30700657D8F9/ItemDetail/p1> ; data: <fault>]" ?

Comment: @Winz Can you post your `ItemDetail.fetchRequest`?